# Federated dbpedia query timeouts with offset > 1000

Tags: sparql, semantics, dbpedia, virtuoso, federated-queries

At this endpoint http://spcdata.digitpa.gov.it:8899/sparql I have a list of all italian municipalities. I want to fetch the population data for every muncipality from dbpedia, and I'm using the `owl:sameAs` property as a pointer to dbpedia .

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797313/sparql-query-from-dbpedia-and-another-graph-returns-less-results-than-expected) you can find the query I'd like to use. Unfortunately,  this query times out roughly over a `LIMIT 1500` clause, so I guessed paginating results using an offset was the best solution.
Unfortunately, this query

```
PREFIX pa:  <http://spcdata.digitpa.gov.it/> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?s a pa:Comune .
  ?s rdf:label ?label .
  ?s owl:sameAs ?sameAs .
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> { 
    ?sameAs dbp:populationTotal ?populationTotal .
   }

} LIMIT 10 offset 6000
```

causes the endpoint to timeout. I've tried with different `OFFSET` values, and below 1000 it works nicely, problems start to arrive when offsetting 1000 and beyond.

What could I do for retrieving all the results? I've tried with the dbpedia endpoint, but seems that federating requests to http://spcdata.digitpa.gov.it:8899/sparql is forbidden.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the timeout explicitly, as a *query parameter*.

the request completed successfully (with `timeout=600000` and `should-sponge=grab-all`)

you can set both parameters also manually from the sparql mask, the `should-sponge` parameter is represented as `retrieve all missing remote RDF data that might be useful` in the html select.

Comment: What is the sponge parameter for? I've tried opening your link but I get this error:
`Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 2: Missing <namespace-iri-string> in PREFIX declaration at '<' before 'http:`

 I've tried with the timeout alone and all I get is an empty table, so I guess the sponge must play an important part here.

Comment: you are right, the link is not working (it got URL encoded twice - probably SO link regex). the sponge parameter means: `retrieve all missing remote RDF data that might be useful` and can be selected from the sparql query mask in the browser. I have updated the answer.